# fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, debian, include, gtk3

im trying to compile a basic code with GTK3+ on Debian11 and i got the following error:

```
fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
```

im using vs code and the autocomplete find the path to the file gtk.h but showme a include errors.

I compile with this command: `gcc main.c -o main 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0'`

The output of `pgk-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`:

```
:~/Code/GTK/gtkTutorial$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
-I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

I try to put the complete path in the `#include </usr/include/gtk-3-0/gtk/gtk.h>` and it give me the next include error for gdk.h file on the gtk.h file.

Both files (gtk.h and gtk.h) exist on my /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/ and /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/ directories.

The code i'm trying to compile is:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    // gtk code comes here

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

any idea, or someone with the same problem?

thanks.

Comment: When you say you use `gcc main.c -o main 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0'`, do you use single quote characters (aka `'`), or do you use backticks (aka `` ` ``)? You should be using the latter (or use the longer `gcc main.c -o main $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)`